# Started computer, home folder moved to a separate volume, all OS settings gone

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory, unmount

Today I started up my computer to find the desktop back to its stock look and my home folder has somehow been plucked and put into a different volume.

How can something like this happen?

[image]

The picture on the left is what my home folder used to be.

I am not an expert in Linux by any stretch so this is really baffling. I need to revert this somehow. All my OS settings are gone like key-bindings, themes etc. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My computer is dual boot with Windows and windows did some automatic update last time I shut off, so can that possibly have done anything here?

edit 1 here is my `/etc/fstab` :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name 
   devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p4 /   ext4  errors=remount-ro 0  1
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p1 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077  0  1
/dev/mapper/isw_baffbgegbh_Volume1p6 /home  ext4 defaults      0 2
```

Comment: For a start, please update your question with the content of /etc/fstab.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this? I have never heard of the `/home` folder moving to a different volume on its own!

Comment: I can not explain how this happened, but could you try commenting the line with /home in fstab and reboot, then login? Does it bring your old home back?

Comment: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Comment: @SebastianStark I tried doing what you said, restarted...I got login screen but when I clicked to log in the screen went black for 3-4 seconds and then went back to login screen. I also tried changing that Volume1p6 volume thats assigned to /home to volume1p7 - which is where my home folder should be and it just didnt let me log in as well.

Comment: Anyone got any clue what this could be ? Basically getting login loop if I replace volume1p6 with volume1p7